# How do I count the amount of words in a list which contain a specific letter?

Tags: python

I am using Python 3. I am looking to create a way for Python to go through all words in a list, and count how many WORDS contain the letter 'e' in them. I am not looking to count the number of 'e' present, only how many words that have one or more of them present.

For example:

Hello, Hi, Whether

I want the program to give the number 2 (as there are two items in the list that contain 'e')

This is the code I have that is not working (I have to count from the listofwords):

```
# defines the text to use
text = "Hello. My name is Elijah Beetle."
lettertocount = "e"

# specifies what punctuation to remove from text
punc = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''

# removes the punctuation from text
for present in text:
    if present in punc:
        text = text.replace(present,"")

listofwords = text.split()

print(listofwords)

countofletter = 0

for counting in listofwords:
    if counting in lettertocount:
        countofletter += 1

print(countofletter)
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: show us ur trial, you will get help when you showed what u have tried.

Comment: `sum(1 for word in listofwords if lettertocount in word.lower())`

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I just posted the code that I currently have tried.

Comment: `if counting in lettertocount:` this is the wrong way round. Change it to `if lettertocount in counting:` and your code will work. Note that you are doing a case-sensitive search, so `Elijah` is not included in the results for `e`.

Comment: @alani Thank you so much!! It is working now!!

Comment: I'd rename `counting` to `word` which then gives a more readable `for word in listofwords:` then as @alani indicated, you'd need to check `if lettertocount in word:`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
def e_words(words):
  e_count = 0
  for i in words:
    if "e" in i:
      e_count += 1
  return e_count
print(e_words(["Hello", "Hi", "Whether"]))
```

The code makes a function called `e_words` that that iterated through the list `words` and added to the variable `e_count` whenever it found "e" in the word.

Comment: Thank you, that information helps me with understanding how the language works!

Answer (score 0):

num = (len([word for word in listofwords if lettertocount in word.lower()]))